# Trying to start animation without stopping current playing animation in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm making UI that show position of something and starts fade-out when point generating function calls. But when fading out dot exists, dot disappears when another function call invoked from inbound communication. How can I prevent disappearing of existing animation?

I want to try create some area for draw new animation when each function call, like Thread, but failed.

This is codes, listener calls DrawRxData when data received.
If function calls, draw and start animation.

DrawRxData.kt

```java
fun DrawRxData (activity: Activity, rxData: RxData) {
    val v : View = activity.findViewById(R.id.DrawRx)
    val iv : ImageView = v as ImageView
    val listView : GridView = activity.findViewById(R.id.list_view)
    var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.measuredWidth, v.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    ...


    ...
    canvas.drawCircle(Xr.toFloat(), Yr.toFloat(), 60F, circPaint)

    val an = AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f)
    an.duration = 10000
    an.fillAfter = true
    iv.alpha = 1f
    ...

    ...
    activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        iv.startAnimation(an)
        listView.adapter = adapter
        listView.setSelection(idx)
        listView.invalidate()
    })

    return
}
```

In C# server program, I achieved easily with adding childrens of canvas. But it looks work different in Android. Can I get link of solutions or  codes?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved with add following codes,

1. Copy Imageview

```
    val v : View = activity.findViewById(R.id.DrawRx)
    val iv : ImageView = v as ImageView
    ...

    ...
    var nv : ImageView
    nv = ImageView(iv.context)
```

2. Start animation in copied Imageview and used `addContentView`

```
    activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
        nv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        nv.startAnimation(an)
        activity.addContentView(nv, params)
        ...
    })
```

`params` is
`var params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`